# Why doesn't `ping -c 1 -W 1800 somehost` succeed when host comes up?

Tags: rhel, ping

I am trying to detect when a host has recovered from a reboot by executing:

```
ping -c 1 -W 1800 myhost
```

I was hoping that before 30 mins passes the host would successfully ping and in my script I could take some action like `ssh` to the host.  But the host DOES boot up before the 30 mins past, which I can verify by manually running `ping myhost` from the command line, but the `ping -c 1 -W 1800 myhost` does not succeed. It just times out.

My OS is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dev-001 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 15 17:36:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I would think the packet would either reach the down server's NIC or be dropped.  And since no further packets are being sent, the server will never receive one while up.

Comment: So should I remove the `-c 1` from the command?

Comment: yes ............

Comment: I believe most of the BSDs implement the `-o` switch for this purpose: `ping -o -t 1800 host` will ping once per second, and return success as soon as one ICMP reply is received, or failure if 1800 seconds elapse without a reply.

Comment: @JimL I don't see an `-o` option from [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/ping.8) - am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @roaima It is present in [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ping&manpath=FreeBSD), [NetBSD](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ping+8+NetBSD-6.0), and [Mac OSX](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/ping/), but not OpenBSD.

Comment: @JimL ha ha just my luck to try the wrong BSD! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your command says is to send one packet (`-c 1`) and wait for up to 30 minutes for the reply (`-W 1800`).

Since the host is presumably down at the point you send the single packet, it's unlikely to be able to send a response, so `ping` waits until the deadline is reached and returns failure.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to "`ping` until success" so you have to synthesise it with a loop. This one waits for up to 1800 seconds, sending one ping every five seconds.

```
end=$(($(date +%s) + 1800))
while [[ $(date +%s) -lt $end ]]
do
    ping -c 1 -i 5 -w 30 -q myhost && break
done
```

Comment: How about if I did `ping -c 1800 -W 1 myhost`?

Comment: You'd be waiting for 30 minutes. Why not try it?

Comment: I am ... waiting 30 mins to see if it works :)